# Access elements of a column and row in a square matrix

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I've a 5x5 square matrix, it was fill by 0 and 1, for example we have element with index = 17, need a cycle which change to reverse values in row and column. Was 1 now 0.[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the op has not tried anything and looks like a HW question

Comment: This question doesn't even say how you store the matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function like this.

```
private int[][] reverse(int[][] arr, int n){
        n=n-1;
        int x = n/arr.length;
        int y = n- (x * n) +1;
        for(int i = 0; i< arr.length;i++){
            for(int j = 0; j< arr[i].length; j++){
                if(x==i || y ==j){
                 arr[i][j] = arr[i][j]==0? 1:0;   
                }
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

There arr is your matrix and n is your index. This works for any square matrix